# Sufficiently proving a sum converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

This might be a bit basic, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong about this so I'd appreciate at least a confirmation that I'm wrong. The question is:

> Prove or disprove:
>
> > If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is positive and converges,  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges as well.

Now my instinct tells me that it's true because if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$, which means  (and here's the part I'm not sure about) that $a_n < 1$, and therefor $a_n^2 < a_n $ so we can use the comparison test to determine that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$  converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges as well.

The problem I have here, again, is the assumption that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ then $a_n < 1$. It also kind of breaks down if $a_n < 0$ though I'm pretty sure (although not entirely confident) that this is not the case because it is stated that "$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is positive".

Any ideas? Am I looking at it wrong?
Should I just in case also try to prove it using the convergence definition?

Comment: For all $n > N$, the rest is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an infinite sum converges this implies that its terms $a_n <1 \ \forall \ n >N$, and for values $|a_n|<1$ clearly $a^2_n < a_n$.

Comment: Of course, I forgot that since we're squaring $a_n$ we might as well be checking absolute convergence, in which case it works either way. Thanks!

Comment: One more question regarding this solution: the same could not be said if we weren't provided with the information that $a_n$ is positive, correct? Because in the case of $a_n$ being a negative or alternating series, we can't say for sure that $a_n^2<a_n$ - am I getting this right?

Comment: Certainly $a^2_n <a_n$ would not hold for alternating sign series. Whether convergence of an alternating sign series would still imply convergence of the squared series is a different question